# Problems reading a .txt file Python

Tags: python

Please help me guys... I do not know how to do this
It should generate 15 random numbers, write the odd ones into a `.txt` file and then read it.

```
import random
f = open('text','w+')
numbers = []
for i in range(15):
    x = random.randint(0,25)
    if x%2 == 1:
        numbers.append(str(x))
        f.write(str(x) + ' ')
print(f.read())
```

Comment: You should open your file in `open('text', 'rw+')` mode. When you finish with writing odd numbers, you should jump to the start of the file using `f..seek(0, 0)` and then read form it.

Comment: @aminrd Please don't post answers as comments, as it bypasses important quality control factors such as downvotes, and also deprives you of those sweet sweet answer points.

Comment: Thanks, that f.seeked helped

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
import random
f = open('text','w+')
numbers = []
#for i in range(15):
while len(numbers) < 15:
    x = random.randint(0,25)
    if x%2 == 1:
        numbers.append(str(x))
        f.write(str(x) + ' ')
f.close()

rf = open('text','r')
print(rf.read())
rf.close()
```

So one of the problems i spotted was that you range 15 but not necessarily every value will be odd.

I also close the file and re-opened it as read.

Answer (score 1):

Open file in "write" mode, write numbers, close it, and then open it in "read" mode. Hope that helps

```
import random
f = open('text.txt','w')
numbers = []
for i in range(15):
    x = random.randint(0,25)
    if x % 2 == 1:
        numbers.append(str(x))
        f.write(str(x) + ' ')
f.close()
f = open('text.txt', 'r')
print(f.read())
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can open your file in `open('text', 'rw+')` mode. When you finish with writing odd numbers, you should jump to the start of the file using `f.seek(0, 0)` and then read form it. Like this:

```
import random
f = open('text','rw+')
numbers = []
for i in range(15):
    x = random.randint(0,25)
    if x%2 == 1:
        numbers.append(str(x))
        f.write(str(x) + ' ')
f.seek(0, 0)
print(f.read())
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the bugs was, if the random number was even, it didn't get added to the file - but the `for i in range(15):` continues to the next iteration - so you don't end up with 15 numbers.

```
import random
numbers = []
# With/open is the preferred technique to write. 
# Use a separate with open to read at the end. 
# Dont try to keep reading and writing from the same file, while it stays open
with open('text','w+') as f: 
    for i in range(15): # This will loop 15 times
        x = random.randint(0,25) # Set the random int first, so the while loop can evaluate
        while x%2 == 0: # if X is even, This will keep looping until it is odd
            x = random.randint(0,25)
        numbers.append(str(x)) # Dont know what this is for
        f.write(str(x) + ' ')

print("----------------")
with open('text','r') as f: 
    print(f.read())
```